# A lisse mixed sheaf as an extension of pure lisse sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, l-adic-sheaves

I am trying to understand Corollary 1.8.11 in Deligne's Weil II paper. The statement is that for a normal scheme $X_0$ that is of finite type over $\mathbb{F}_q$, every lisse $\ell$-adic $\iota$-mixed sheaf $\mathscr{F}_0$ on $X_0$ is an extension of pointwise $\iota$-pure lisse $\ell$-adic sheaves on $X_0$.

My question is rather basic: how is this statement not a tautology? By definition given in 1.2.6 of that article, a constructible $\ell$-adic sheaf is $\iota$-mixed if it is a successive extension of $\iota$-pure sheaves. Moreover, a subsheaf or a quotient of a lisse sheaf is again lisse (because lisse sheaves are the same as $\ell$-adic representations of $\pi_1$), so isn't 1.8.11 essentially a restatement of the definition? I am confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Subqotients of lisse sheaves are not necessarily lisse: if $j:U\to X$ is an open immersion with complement $i:Z\to X$ then $j_{!}\mathbb{Q}_{l,U}$ is a subsheaf of $\mathbb{Q}_{l,X}$ and $i_*\mathbb{Q}_{l,Z}$ is its quotient.